# ejabberd stops when I am adding mod_http_offline to ejabberd.cfg

Tags: ejabberd

I am using ejabberd 2.1.10 for implementing the mod_http_offline mod for IOS push notification. I tried to do this using two solutions like

http://jasonrowe.com/2011/12/30/ejabberd-offline-messages/

&

https://github.com/adamvduke/mod_interact

But both the time when I am adding Modules to the ejabberd configuration file It stops the server and return the below error in the log

ERROR REPORT==== 2014-01-28 15:09:13 ===
C(<0.41.0>:gen_mod:75) : Problem starting the module mod_http_offline for host "23.23.191.229"
options: []
error: function_clause

Comment: Post the link to the [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/)'ed snippet of your configuration file where you inserted clauses to enable your module--99% of such errors are related to violating the rules of Erlang sytnax.  Also please pastebin the full error message and possibly some context around it.  Extract it from the relevant log file.

Comment: Thanks for replying. please look into this .. http://pastebin.com/E1zVw4qv

Comment: Please check pastebin file for configuration. Please help me on this.

Comment: I don't know how to help: the configuration file looks correct to me: usually people tend to lose commas when inserting module configuration snippets but your file looks OK.  I'm afraid there's a problem with the module itself or may be API mismatch between the module and ejabberd. I'd try to file an issue with the [module's bug tracker](https://github.com/adamvduke/mod_interact/issues).